# How do UIWebView and UIScrollView manage RGB and hexa Colors?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am encountering a strange problem :

I added a `UIWebView` in a `UIScrollView`. I tried to apply a background color for both.

- For the `UIScrollView` I used Interface Builder and I specified a RGB coded color : `255 0 0 (100% red)`.
- For the `UIWebView` I specified a Hexa coded color by using :

  ```
  [self.myWebView loadHTMLString:@"<style>body {background-color:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF;}</style>text"];
  ```

Well, it seems the both item don't understand colors (which are equals : `#FF0000` <=> `RGB(255, 0, 0))` the same way.
Actually, I get a darker red color in my `UIScrollView`, and something which looks like a real 100% red in my `UIWebView`.

Two important things :

- I do not apply any opacity or alpha property on both of `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView`
- When I try to specify `#000000` / `RGB(0, 0, 0)` or `#FFFFFF` / `RGB(255, 255, 255)`, I get the exact same color in both of my View.

So here is my question :
Is there any difference between the way the both class manage colors ?
Or any difference between RGB and Hexa colors ?

Comment: Curious, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Here : http://img638.imageshack.us/i/capturedcran20110415144.png/ (it's written in French)

Comment: how did you make that screenshot? because for me both are not completely red (using the color picker)

Comment: Cmd + Shift + 4 (Mac OS X). I sayed __something which looks like__. I didn't used a color picker to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference. I just recreated you example and it does look exactly the same. Look at these screenshots below. I load the webview like this:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:
 @"<html><body style='background-color:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF;'>text</body></html>" baseURL:nil];
```

The color picker sets the color of the UIScrollView.

There must be something in your code or something about the webview and your css that alters the color.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you try to add the UIWebView in the UIScrollView (with addSubview I mean) ? By the way I tried to specify the background color of my UIScrollView programmatically :  `myScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];` and it's working ! Does it mean the problem comes from Interface Builder ?

Comment: Ugh... I removed my only single line of code which is specifiyng a background color in my code (written above), and re-specified it in IB. Guess what.. it's working. Meaningless... Anyway, thanks for great answer.